# Inside div placing span next to p element

Tags: css

Here is my code

```
     <div>
        <p>hello nirmesh</p>
        <span> <img src="x.png"/></span>
     </div>
```

I want is to show image next to my `<p>` tag and not below it. Please anyone help me to resolve this

Comment: make your p `display:inline-block`

Comment: Are you able to alter the markup, placing the `span` within the `p`?

Answer (score 0):

Making the p tag, which is defaulted to "block" an "inline-block" element, will let other elements flow along after it. It's best to add these rules in an external stylesheet, but for illustration:

```
<div>
  <p style="inline-block; margin-right: 5px;>hello nirmesh</p>
  <span><img src="x.png"/></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Good point. "hello nirmesh" looks like it's going to be multiline :)

Comment: Reread the question; it's stated that the text in the `p` could be any length.

Comment: Oh yes, my bad, sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
  <p style="display:inline-block;>hello nirmesh</p>
  <span> <img src="x.png"/></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the display of the `p` tag to `inline`.

```css
p {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>hello nirmesh</p>
  <img src="x.png"/>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks it worked but that image should appear at center of text. How i can achieve the same?

Comment: what do you mean by center of text? can you please elaborate with a little overview of what you're trying to do?

Comment: check this "http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2375504/3bb5365d08ec38b63662307781c3b734" you can see image is little below i want it aligned to text that's it.

Comment: The link is just opening the landing page of the website, can you share the correct link.